# AJAX request not working in ie9 - Google Maps API/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have Google maps on my page, my visitors can drag a maker from outside of the google maps canvas window and on the release of the marker an input field is populated.

My function works fine in all browsers ***but*** ie9.

```
function GetLocation(location) {
var result;
$.ajax({
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + location + "&components=country:UK&sensor=false",
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        result = data;
        alert("result: " + result);
    }
});

return result;
}


$(".startPoint").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        var mOffset = $(map.getDiv()).offset();
        var point = new google.maps.Point(
        ui.offset.left - mOffset.left + (ui.helper.width() / 2),
        ui.offset.top - mOffset.top + (ui.helper.height()));
        var ll = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);

        var address = GetAddress(ll.k, ll.B);
        if (address.status == 'OK') {
            placeMarker(ll, address.results[0].formatted_address, 'img/startLoc.png', $('#startLocation'));
            $('#startLocation').val(address.results[0].formatted_address);

        } else {
            alert('Could not find an address');
        }
    }
});
```

The above fails and I've no idea why - can anybody advise me in the best way to debug this issue?

---

**Console Errors**

Unable to get the value of the property 'status': object is null or undefined

Comment: any console errors???

Comment: u have to send status also from querystring..

Comment: You obviously have included the javascript-API, why don't you use the geocoding-service of this API(it's recommended for clientside usage) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding